# making a function that run after certain condition in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to build a [Line chatbot](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python) that when a POST requests is received and will parse the receive POST requests information to the chatbot users.

```
import os
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json

from flask import Flask, request, abort,Response,jsonify

import requests

from linebot import (
    LineBotApi, WebhookHandler
)
from linebot.exceptions import (
    InvalidSignatureError, LineBotApiError
)
from linebot.models import (
    MessageEvent, TextMessage, TextSendMessage,SourceUser
)

app = Flask(__name__)

data=''

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    
    """devicename,exceptionType,temperature,mask,stranger"""
    device_name = request.form.get('device_name')
    exceptionType = request.form.get('exceptionType')
    temperature = request.form.get('temperature')
    mask = request.form.get('mask')
    stranger = request.form.get('stranger')

    global data

    data=f"device_name = {device_name} exceptionType = {exceptionType} temperature = {temperature} mask = {mask} stranger = {stranger}"
    
    return_status = {"success":"true"}
    return jsonify(return_status)

while len(data) > 1:
    try:
        line_bot_api.broadcast(
                messages=TextSendMessage(text=str(data))
                )
        data=''
    except LineBotApiError as e:
        raise e
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg_parser = ArgumentParser(
        usage='Usage: python ' + __file__ + ' [--port <port>] [--help]'
    )
    arg_parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=8000, help='port')
    arg_parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', default=False, help='debug')
    options = arg_parser.parse_args()

    app.run(debug=options.debug, port=options.port)
```

here I have two parts, first is the POST requests receiver. and second is the part that checks the condition if `data` is present. But when I send the POST requests, the `line_bot_api.broadcast` does not send the message to the chatbot user. I only saw examples of flask code that has a `@app.route()` so I was wondering if something like this works? or is there a better way to implement the condition (instead of checking `data` value, is it better to check if function `get_data()` ran or requests has been sent to our `/data` route)

Answer (score 1):

The while loop stops immediately because the condition fails. One way to get around this and do what you want is by using threads.

```
import os
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json
import threading

from flask import Flask, request, abort,Response,jsonify

import requests

from linebot import (
    LineBotApi, WebhookHandler
)
from linebot.exceptions import (
    InvalidSignatureError, LineBotApiError
)
from linebot.models import (
    MessageEvent, TextMessage, TextSendMessage,SourceUser
)

app = Flask(__name__)

data=''

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():

    """devicename,exceptionType,temperature,mask,stranger"""
    device_name = request.form.get('device_name')
    exceptionType = request.form.get('exceptionType')
    temperature = request.form.get('temperature')
    mask = request.form.get('mask')
    stranger = request.form.get('stranger')

    global data

    data=f"device_name = {device_name} exceptionType = {exceptionType} temperature = {temperature} mask = {mask} stranger = {stranger}"

    return_status = {"success":"true"}
    return jsonify(return_status)

def broadcast():
    while True:
        if len(data) < 1 : continue
        try:
            line_bot_api.broadcast(
                    messages=TextSendMessage(text=str(data))
                    )
            data=''
        except LineBotApiError as e:
            raise e



if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg_parser = ArgumentParser(
        usage='Usage: python ' + __file__ + ' [--port <port>] [--help]'
    )
    arg_parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=8000, help='port')
    arg_parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', default=False, help='debug')
    options = arg_parser.parse_args()

    broadcast_thread = threading.Thread(target=broadcast)
    broadcast_thread.start()

    app.run(debug=options.debug, port=options.port)
```

This is definitely not the best way. But it works.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, unfortunately, the message is still not sent to the Line user. but I think the problem now is within `line_bot_api.broadcast()`. This is also my first time learning the use of `threading`.